# Python WSDL function parameters are not accepted

Tags: php, python, soap, wsdl

I can send function arguments to a SOAP client in PHP like this (`searchLinks` is a method name):

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://linksearch.api.cj.com/wsdl/version2/linkSearchServiceV2.wsdl",   array('trace'=> true));
$results = $client->searchLinks(array("developerKey" => $developerKey,
                                             "token" => '',
                                         "websiteId" => $websiteId,
                                     "advertiserIds" => 'joined'));
```

If I want to do the same thing in Python, how can I do this? This is the present code:

```
server=WSDL.Proxy(url)
results=server.searchLinks({'developerkey':dev_key,'token':'','websiteId':website_id,'advertiserIds':'joined'})
```

When I try to run this Python script, it throws errors. Why is it not taking function parameters like in PHP?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the parameters the correct way in the python version ?  Should all the arguments be passed in a dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

Which library are you using,

Assuming that you are using SOAPpy, You can do .

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import SOAPpy

url= 'https://linksearch.api.cj.com/wsdl/version2/linkSearchServiceV2.wsdl'
proxy = SOAPpy.WSDL.Proxy(url)
results=proxy.searchLinks({'developerkey': 'dev_key','token':'','websiteId': 'website_id','advertiserIds':'joined'})
```

Comment: I used the same library, SOAPpy.WSDL but still no hint, whats going on? would you like to see the python code

Comment: using suds, I am able to solve my problem, I wonder why shouldn't we put '' quotes.